# How to send the request with errors in the email content in JMeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a script in JMeter that validates the load test of multiple Urls/requests. The test is configured/integrated in Jenkins and I am sending an email once the test is complete but I want to include in the content of the email the request with an error status. In the email content, I want to include the request/url and the status code. For example, the content will look like this in table format.

| URL | Status Code |
| --- | --- |
| www.test.com | 500 |
| www.test2.com | 504 |

Can anyone help how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to send the statistics you need to collect it first, the easiest way is using [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener configured like:

[image]

When your main Thread Group completes you will be able to send the file from [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) as the attachment

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)